# Mortgage documents vs Credit report: am I mortgage-less now?

Tags: united-states, mortgage, credit, legal, illinois

I live in Chicago IL area, and had some issues with paying my mortgage over the past 2 & 1/2 years. The original mortgage company ended up selling to another company after I filed chapter 7 bankruptcy. I then received a statement from the new company with the full amount of the mortgage, saying they were the new owners of the debt.

After a few months of never getting another statement from them or anyone, I had to buy a new car. Checking my credit score I noticed something odd: Both mortgage companies' status is listed as Closed Accounts with $0 payments due.

**Which brings me to my questions**:

1) Am I mortgage-less now?

2) Where is my deed and or title?

3) Did the mortgage companies just write if off as a loss due to the amount left on the home?

4) How do I look into paying the property tax which I still need to get adjusted before the next tax installment?

5) Should I still consider moving?

There haven't been anymore court dates either for a while now. The house was bought at $60k in a area where there are a lot of people either losing their homes or having to sell. I don't want to lose my home if I really don't have to; I hate this stressful situation that took me and my family by surprise.

Comment: If you filed Chapter 7, your property and mortgage would certainly have been listed in your filing. You should talk to your bankruptcy trustee.

Comment: Side question - Should you be borrowing money to buy a car when you can't afford your mortgage?

Comment: Did you reaffirm any debts during your chapter 7?

Answer (score 3):

Go to your local tax assessors office or recorder of deeds. They should be able to tell you who holds the title and give you a copy. In fact, a lot of this information is available online just by looking up your address. I don't know which county you live in, but in Cook County, the web site is [here](http://www.cookcountyassessor.com/Search/Property-Search.aspx).

PS... Why don't you call the mortgage company and ask what the situation is? Better to know than to live in uncertainty.

Comment: Because if he calls, that reminds the mortgage company that they're owed money.

Comment: @mkennedy, not if it wasn't reaffirmed in the bankruptcy...

Comment: @quid: That's a really odd result because bankruptcy doesn't prevent secured loans from collecting the property that secures them.

Comment: Google reaffirmation agreement.